# microsoft macros, how to use shell()?

Tags: vbscript, macros

I have the following code as a macro in microsoft word 2007:

```
Sub AutoExec()
    MsgBox "hello"
    Dim RetVal
    Set RetVal = Shell("wscript.exe C:\Docs\test.vbs", 1)
End Sub
```

However I get a compile error on the word 'Shell' (Error is 'Object required'). How do I fix this as everywhere I looked gave the same syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Shell](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Shell-Function-ff2e4b1b-712d-4e34-aea6-6832eadd3c63) returns an ID, not an object. So change

```
Set RetVal = Shell("wscript.exe C:\Docs\test.vbs", 1)
```

to

```
RetVal = Shell("wscript.exe C:\Docs\test.vbs", 1)
```